# How to test if string contains another string in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I can't seem to find an assertion in [**PHPUnit**](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html) that simply tests if a string is contained somewhere in another string. Trying to do something like this:

```
public function testRecipe() {

    $plaintext = get_bread_recipe();

    $this->assertStringContains('flour', $plaintext);

}
```

What real assertion would I put instead of `assertStringContains` ? I would prefer not having to worry about regex in this case because there is absolutely no need for it.

It's so simple that there must be something I have overlooked, but I just can't figure it out! Funny enough there is `assertStringStartsWith()` and `assertStringEndsWith()`!

**Update:** I know `strpos() !== false` could be used but I'm looking for something cleaner. If I just use vanilla PHP functions anyway what's the whole point with all the assertions then...

Comment: There's no such method to do that, however you can use `$this->assertGreaterThan(0, strpos($plaintext, 'flour'));`

Comment: @bartek That will fail if the string starts with 'flour'

Comment: @GordonM Right, in this case `-1` will do the trick

Comment: @bartek That still won't work. You have to do a strict test for FALSE

Comment: See, this is exactly why I wanted that specific assertion - the confusion is already evident here!

Comment: @TheStoryCoder Welcome to PHP development :)

Comment: You can always extend the PHPUnit testing to add your own assert. I think this is messy, but you could include your own set of routines in the bootstrap.php file.  For this same test though, we simply assertEquals, assertTrue, etc... and use the basic PHP functions.  PHPUnit is a testing framework, not a complete replacement for PHP functionality.

Comment: Another reason this function would be great to have is for doing comparisons of result and expected values in IDEs such as PhpStorm. Comparing "True" and "False" is really not that helpful, whereas being able to examine the haystack itself would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Steven Scott If that is really your opinion then why on earth do we have assertEquals and assertTrue?!!

Comment: @TheStoryCoder We use the assertEquals() with tolower() etc... to accomplish what you are trying.  The asserts are used to ensure our testing in PHPUnit throws the errors to fail builds, etc...  I am not sure which opinion you are wondering about though?  PHP is still very useful in the tests, with the PHPUnit framework combining the test structure and reporting.

Comment: I always find myself coming back to this answer about how to do the equivalent of stringContains in `with()` using Mockery https://stackoverflow.com/a/46922330/470749

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As you could tell `assertContains` is for checking that an array contains a value.

Looking to see if the string contains a substring, your simplest query would be to use [assertMatchesRegularExpression()](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.4/assertions.html#assertmatchesregularexpression)

```
$this->assertMatchesRegularExpression('/flour/', $plaintext);
```

You would just need to add the delimiters.

If you really want to have an `assertStringContains` assertion, you can extend `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` and create your own.

**UPDATE**

In the **pre-9** versions of PHPUnit, `assertContains` will work on strings.

From **9+** we need to use `assertStringContainsString` or `assertStringContainsStringIgnoringCase`.

Comment: More recent versions of phpunit can do assertContains string.

Comment: Update in v9 : assertStringContainsString or assertStringContainsStringIgnoringCase

Comment: We can use these methods of PHPUnit:  
assertStringContainsString() or assertStringContainsStringIgnoringCase()  
AND  
assertStringNotContainsString() or assertStringNotContainsStringIgnoringCase()  
  
By the way note that assertContains() with string haystacks is deprecated and will not be supported in PHPUnit 9.

Comment: @schleis UPDATE assertContains doesn't work anymore on string (9.5.20)
Had to use `assertTrue(str_contains(...̀

Answer (score 83):

### 2019+ and PHPUnit 8.0+ update

`assertContains()` is deprecated since PHPUnit 8.0, see [issue #3425](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3425).

Now the specific method is recommended (see [`issue #3422`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3422)):

```php
$plaintext = 'I fell on the flour';
$this->assertStringContainsString('flour', $plaintext);
```

TIP: Upgrade instantly with [Rector and PHPUnit 8.0 set](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/blob/master/config/set/phpunit80.php).

Comment: Clear answer, to the point and updated to latest version. This is the valid reply for me. I see other answers with higher score, but if the framework has an specific method for this I don't see why use workarounds like "assertRegexp".

Comment: Workarounds were for older versions. This is the correct answer for PHPUnit 8+.

Answer (score 78):

You can always hide the ugliness inside a custom assertion method, so basically I would have a BaseTestCase class which inherits from the phpunit test case which you could use to have your own library of reusable assertions (see http://xunitpatterns.com/Custom%20Assertion.html).. (In php 5.4 you can use traits as well, imho assertion libraries are one of the cases where traits actually are useful)..I always introduce quite a few custom assertions in my projects, often domain specific. And yes, some are ugly too:) well, I guess that's what encapsulation is there for... Amongst things...:)

**UPDATE:**
I just checked and 'assertContains' and 'assertNotContains' actually also operate on strings as well as arrays (and anything that implements 'Traversable'):

```
function test_Contains()
{
    $this->assertContains("test", "this is a test string" );
    $this->assertNotContains("tst", "this is a test string");
}
```

Comment: PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Argument #2 (No Value) of PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertContains() must be a array, traversable or string

Comment: this behaviour is deprecated

Comment: Was fine in 2015 but under PHP 8.1 throws a fatal error: `TypeError: PHPUnit\Framework\Assert::assertContains(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type iterable, string given`. We can migrate to assertStringContainsString.

Answer (score -1):

You can do asserts against anything, including vanilla PHP functions.  If you assert that strpos for the substring you're interested in on the string you're testing doesn't return FALSE it will meet your needs.

Make sure you're checking against FALSE though, and not something that evaluates to FALSE such as 0 (which is what strpos will return if the string being tested starts with the given substring).

Comment: I just wanted something cleaner than using strpos() for that very reason you are mentioning! But I guess it just doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

Extending from @Schleis, if you have more complicated strings you will need to escape the regex:

```
$this->assertRegexp('/' . preg_quote('[some $stuff]') . '/', $plaintext);
```

Or wrap it up in a neater method:

```
public function assertStringContains($needle, $haystack)
{
    $this->assertRegexp('/' . preg_quote($needle) . '/', $haystack);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can't you just do the string in string using the plain PHP functions available, and then assertEquals the output of that? Granted, it's not as shiny, but it works.

Alternatively you can use assertThat with a regular expression.

It sounds like something is inherently wrong with the design of the code / test though, from the limited perspective of the example. Why would a function return a complex string of unknown length, with the expected bit 'somewhere' in the string?

In the test you should be able to control your input, so you should know your entire expected output string. If your function ruins other parts of the string just this assertion wouldn't tell you about it. Which is probably why the assertStringContains function doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for the shiny way to do it. I'm testing retrieving a webpage to which I have posted variables so I want to test if the request was OK based on whether or not a string exists in that page. Can't see how I can do that any differently.